# Erro ao inciar PYGAME

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Estou criando uma replica simples do jogo Space Invaders em Python3.7, no começo estava criando a tela tudo com Turtle, mas o jogo entrava em uma especie de loop infinito e não executava os comandos. Apos um amigo ter sugerido usar a bib pygame desenvolvi o codigo abaixo.

**Codigo:**

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import pygame

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Cria a borda
border_pen = Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-270, -260)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)

for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(530)
    border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()

#Cria a nave do usuario
player = Turtle()
player.color("blue")
player.shape("triangle")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0, -200)
player.setheading(90)

playerspeed = 10

#Mover a nave
def move_left():
    x = player.xcor()
    x -= playerspeed
    player.setx(x)

def move_right():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += playerspeed
    player.setx(x)

#Cria movimento de tecla
screen = Screen()
screen.listen()
screen.onkey(move_left, "Left")
screen.onkey(move_right, "Right")

crashed = False

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

**Estou tendo o seguinte erro:**

```
2019-04-12 15:44:18.808 Python[9273:62443] -[PYGSDLApplication 
_setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe3adf83cf0
2019-04-12 15:44:18.815 Python[9273:62443] *** Terminating app due to 
uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '- 
[PYGSDLApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
0x7fe3adf83cf0'
*** First throw call stack: { ... }

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type 
NSException
```

Comment: como você instalou esse pygame? Que sistema operacional está usando?

Answer (score 1):

O pygame não foi feito para "conversar" com o tkinter, onde roda o turtle - o seu programa está frankestenico no estado atual, criando as duas interfaces - em teoria, não deveria haver conflitos - cada biblioteca teria a sua janela e até seria possível com alguns ajustes usar as duas simultaneamente (do jeito que está não, por que as chamadas que você colocou ao "Turtle" bloqueiam o programa). Mas também pode ser a causa do  seu problema - ou é isso, ou o pygame está quebrado no seu sistema.

Como vocẽ não disse como instalou o pygame, nem que sistema operacional está usando, é tudo o que dá pra dizer -

Tente criar um programa mínimo, só de pygame, sem importar o turtle (só abra a janela, espere um tempo e feche) - depois você vai criando o código conforme for funcionando.

E verifique também como você instalou o pygame -  o correto é instalar pela linha de comando com `pip install pygame` - se você baixou um instalador de algum site, pode ser a causa do seu erro.

Enquanto isso, vocẽ pode tentar pegar o código usando só o turtle mesmo, no ponto em que estava antes, e criar uma nova pergunta, sobre ele - acredito que dê sim pra criar um space invaders usando o turtle, e pode ser um exercício interessante.

Eu devo ter algum space-invaders usando pygame no github também, se quiser ter uma idéia de estrutura - em geral eu uso de exemplo quando dou oficinas de programação - (olhando lá) - não, tenho um desenvolvido para rodar no navegador, com  o Brython - mas não com Pygame. Esse esa complicado de instalar por que depende de uma versão antiga do brython - mas ainda assim acho que está um código limpo e legal para um Space Invaders: https://github.com/jsbueno/browser_invaders